# Can I get whitespace-mode to display a sequence of two leading spaces , specially?

Tags: whitespace

Like this: 
[image]

I have been able to get whitespace-mode to display dots for leading spaces.

[image]

But I want to specially display each sequence of 2 leading spaces, with maybe a vertical bar.

Possible?

Maybe not with whitespace-mode?

As a separate question, how do I get whitespace-mode to display only leading spaces as middle-dot?

I have

```
    whitespace-space-regexp "\\(^ +\\)"
```

...but that seems only to apply to the FACE used, not to the character substitution.

I've been fiddling with this for 20 minutes. I'm amazed that I still have not cracked this. Doesn't everyone want something like this?

Comment: The existing vertical bar solutions in Elisp are not that good, but you may wish to play around with `vline.el` and the libraries that build upon / modify that library.  I am working on feature requests 17684 and 22873 in my spare time, but I am probably a year or two (or more) away from perfecting them.  [It just depends upon how spare time I have, combined with motivation ...  The next patch proof concept will probably be available in about a month or so ...]  Fill-column-indicator by Alp Aker may also be of interest to you -- it an be tweaked ...

Comment: See also:  https://superuser.com/a/608910/206164 and other threads that can be found with Googling things like:  emacs vertical highlight; emacs verticular ruler, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on font-lock and `compose-region`, I can sort of get emacs to do what I want. This stuff:

```
(defun yaml-pretty-search-leading-ws (limit)
  "Function to search for leading whitespace, and invoke
`compose-region' on ranges within it, to display the whitespace
differently: display a dot and a vertical bar for the sequence.

This fn is intended to be invoked indirectly via font-lock as a
search/matcher. It doesn't return a positive match to font-lock.

At the finish, all of the leading whitespace up to LIMIT should
be composed and fontified."

  (let ((start (point)))
    (save-match-data ;; we don't want font-lock to fontify.
      ;; 2 consecutive spaces
      (while (re-search-forward "  " limit t)
        (let ((start (match-beginning 0))
              (stop (match-end 0)))
          (put-text-property start stop 'face 'yaml-pretty-leading-ws-face)
          (compose-region start (1- stop) ?·)
          (compose-region (1- stop) stop ?|)
          )))))

(defvar yaml-pretty-flock-keywords
  '((yaml-pretty-search-leading-ws . yaml-pretty-leading-ws-face)))

(font-lock-add-keywords nil yaml-pretty-flock-keywords)
```

Results in :

[image]

For static text display, this is exactly what I wanted.

Now I need to get it to do the inverse -  "un-compose" the region, and remove the face property  - as I modify the leading whitespace.